# Using Chrome, how can I remove text advertisments from Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, ads

I use AdBlocker as an extension for Google Chrome. It does a very good job on  removing commercials, but doesn't remove the text advertisements in Gmail. Is there some way to also remove the text ads in Gmail?

**Edit**: Actually the problem was Web Clips and not ads. I installed Better Gmail and it tooled me about Settings -> Web Clips which I could turn off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Better GMail](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gmfocnipihcoejdieiimhiecclokidea) extension has an option to do this.

Comment: Better Gmail is long gone.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Greasemonkey userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/37693) which removes the adverts (I've just tested it) but it causes some style errors with some links moving slightly.

As Greasemonkey is now built into Chrome you will be able to install it by simply hitting "Install" on the userscript page and it will install as a regular extension.